# SP2007 SPSiteDataQuery - Exclude user permissions from a specific group

Tags: 2007, permissions, spsitedataquery

We have a site (SP2007) with approx 1000 second-level sub-sites. We would like all users to have read access to all of the lists in the sub-sites (inherited). In addition, if the user is a member of the sub-site, they also get some extra contribute rights (sub-siteXXX membership group).

Now, we want to do SiteCollection list queries and limit the returned data based on where the currentUser is a member of the sub-site. Out of the box, SharePoint does a good job of limiting results based on whether the user has read access to the list. But, how can I limit it to "sub-site group members" only when all users belong to an inherited group which gives everyone read access to all sub-site lists?

Comment: Do you have the freedom to write server side code for this? Also, indirectly what you are telling is get data from lists of all sub sites in which current user has contribute rights given through the sub-siteXXX group.

Comment: Yes, I have freedom to write either server or client side code. In regards to "contribute rights given through the sub-siteXXX group"; Yes, they are granted limited contribution rights through their membership in the various siteXXX groups. Got some ideas on how to do this? - bitFlinger